# Twitter timeline issue with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, twitter, whitelist

since updating to latest version of PhoneGap a Twitter timeline no longer works on iDevices (just a blank page).
The html works fine on desktop Safari and on mobile Safari but not in a PhoneGap build. Googling the issue focuses on whitelisting but my config.xml files all contain

```
<access origin="*" />
```

and I added ExternalHosts to the plist file.
I also added the domains in Capabilities/Associated-Domains and still no tweets displayed.
Any further ideas on solving this gratefully received.
thanks

PS a further oddity: when I tried the Jquery add-on 'tweecool' I get tweets displayed in the App (although not as well formatted as the Twitter Timeline, hence my continued interest in solving this).